# Use of Command, printf (type and method) in Java trigger errors

Tags: java

Is there any shortcut in Eclipse to import all required classes? A combination of keys?

For example I used the keyword Command and I'm not sure what to import because it doesn't recognize Command as type. 
I also have this error:
The method `printf(String, Object[])` in the type Console is not applicable for the arguments `(String, int)`.

I think it needs me to import some packages that incorporate some of the methods that I am using which aren't in the default package. Any help appreciated. 
Thanks! Sam

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse ide quick fix all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761639/eclipse-ide-quick-fix-all)

Comment: It will only suggest classes on the current project's classpath. If there isn't a `Command` on the classpath, it won't know what to import. If there are multiple `Command`s on the classpath, it will ask you. If *you* don't know which to import, Eclipse can't help you.

Comment: Thanls assylias! However if I do CTRL+SHIFT+O I get this: "Compilation unit has parse errors. Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 5.0. No changes applied."

Comment: @Sam If I had to take a guess, that means you've got an error else-where

Comment: @Sam Then you *also* need to set up your project for the JDK version you actually want to use.

Comment: @Sam You seem to be using annotations (like `@Override`) and your compiler is setup to an older version that does not support them

Comment: Ctrl-3, type `compiler - java`, select the only option. There set the source level appropriately. Also check Project Properties, Java Compiler (you could have Project-specific setting for source level).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure Eclipse uses a source level of at least Java 5, otherwise var-args aren't implemented.

Comment: Hello, veer. Thank you. So by just downloading and installing an update from oracle.com, this would be fixed? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html: I found this - Java SE 7 downloads.

Comment: @Sam you should have a newer JDK already. You want to change the __Compiler Compliance Level__ setting.