# Eclipse Fix all Problems?

Tags: eclipse

I am in making of an analog Clock in Eclipse. After very hard struggle I am unable to create it. The reason is Error/Problems in Eclipse I want to know how to clear all Error one by one or all in once ?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6766961/6309

Comment: Dear, Often, you can fix errors en masse. There are several ways. I recommend going to your Problems view, selecting one of the errors, and hitting Ctrl-1 (quick fix). It should offer you the chance to fix all the errors of the selected type, in all files.

You can also mouse over the error in the text editor and wait for a popup; it should say "fix 70 other errors of this type". Doing it this way applies only to the specific file.....--->>>I will be too much thankful VonC If you explain here little more in an easy way because I am a Begginer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse ide quick fix all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761639/eclipse-ide-quick-fix-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main documentation for the [latest Eclipse Luna 4.4](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna) is: "[Quick Fix](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-java-editor-quickfix.htm) "

> Left click on the light bulb or invoking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (`Edit > Quick Fix`) brings up the proposals for the problem at the cursor position.
>   Each quick fix shows a preview when selected in the proposal window.

[image: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/images/c-quickfix.png]

> Some quick fixes offer to fix all problems of the same kind in the current file at once.
>   The information text in the proposal window contains this information for all applicable proposals. To fix all problems of the same kind, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Remember: this won't apply to *all* types of errors, only to certain errors.

Comment: Thank you VonC...I will try to get rid of all my problems in Eclipse Once Again Thank you for your HELP